# accessing mic and earphone of android cellphone

Tags: android

hey can anybody please tel me that can i access a mic and earphone of my android cell,as we can access camera hardware of cellphone so is there any way to access them as i want to make a walky-talky app.And im a very beginner so please help me out thanks evry1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AudioRecord`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) to record the audio.

Check some Android audio chat (SIP) projects to how they have done it:

http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/

http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/

Comment: thanks alot...im now working on this work and if i get stuck ill again disturb you:)

Answer (score 0):

Well that would be android.media.AudioRecord for the mic and android.media.AudioTrack for the sound. But what you want to do won't be something for beginner. You should at least be able to find this in the android api.

I suggest you to start with a less complex program. On the android developer site, you will find a good start for this.
http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html